# Sencha iOS picker bug

Tags: ios, extjs, cordova, picker

My app is nearly completed, but there's one bug which I have to get sorted before release. The app uses Cordova 3.4 and Sencha to build a "native" app for iOS and Android (the bug only relates to iOS)

Basically, when the picker value is changed, unless the user is quick enough in how they click Done, it reverts to the previous value - hard to explain! [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dffsxy1epxe97ak/Picker%20bug.mp4) is a video showing the bug in action.

As mentioned before, this is only a problem on iOS (Android is fine). It is also worth noting that when there are two value options in other pickers in the app this bug does not exist. For example, the picker for time (hours & minutes) and date (day & month) do not have this bug - only single value pickers have the issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just had to fix this issue within our product, and boy debugging on the iPhone is a right pain when you only have a Windows desktop!

Essentially what seemed to be happening was that when a slot's selection changed, the internal selectedIndex property was being updated, however the _value was not - and it seems that it's the _value that is being consulted.

I created a new slot class as follows, that overrides doItemTap to ensure that value is set appropriately (`me._value = me.getValue(true);`):

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.FixedSlot', {  
  extend: 'Ext.picker.Slot',
  xtype : 'fixedslot',
  doItemTap: function(list, index, item, e, event) {
      var me = this;
      me.selectedIndex = index;
      me.selectedNode = item;
      me._value = me.getValue(true);
      me.scrollToItem(item, true);
  }
});
```

Then in my picker definition config (we have a class defined as a subclass of field.Select), I instructed it to use my new slot type (`defaultType: 'fixedslot'`):

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.MyFixedPicker', {
  extend: 'Ext.field.Select',
  config : {
    defaultPhonePickerConfig : { defaultType: 'fixedslot' }
  }
});
```

I'm hoping that helps you avoid some of the pain of my last six hours!  I still can't explain exactly why/where in the Sencha Touch source that's important, but for right now it appears to fix the problem and meet our packaging deadline!